# Unable to run sudo command on linux

Tags: centos, permissions, sudo, chmod

I am using Linux CentOS but suddenly I couldn't run sudo command. I got below errors. Even with root user it got the same error.

```
$ sudo ls
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Below is the permission on this file:

```
 ls -l /etc/sudoers
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4241 Jun  9 20:36 /etc/sudoers
# which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
# ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
--ws-wx-wx. 1 root root 130712 Jun 10  2014 /usr/bin/sudo
```

What wrong with the system? How can I fix it?

**EDIT1**

Please see below command output:

```
# ls -Z /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- root root ?                                /etc/sudoers
```

I have run chmod 440 on this file but it seems the permission is broken.

**EDIT2**

I run below command to set the /etc/sudoers permission but it still not correct:

```
root@Cool-Too ~]# chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
[root@Cool-Too ~]# ll /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 4241 Aug 14 22:16 /etc/sudoers
[root@Cool-Too ~]# ll -Z /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- root root ?                                /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: On CentOS, there are probably corrupted SELinux permissions.  Try `restorecon /etc/sudoers`  (as root).

Comment: Permissions are odd, they usually should be `440` for `/etc/sudoers` (i.e. `-r--r----- root root`). Use `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` (as root) - if the problem persists use `visudo` and check if there are syntax errors in your sudoers file.

Comment: Those permissions are *really* strange. Beware, even if you fix sudo, there may be other things that are broken. This doesn't happen on its own… Did you run strange commands recently?

Answer (score 2):

Your permissions are very off, indeed.

They should be similar to:

```
-r--r----- 1 root root   4188 Mar 31 11:30 /etc/sudoers
---s--x--x 1 root root 130720 Mar 31 13:09 /usr/bin/sudo
```

To fix this, as root

```
chmod 4111 /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

If you see a `+` sign in the `ls -l` output then it means there are also ACLs set; these should be removed

```
setfacl -b /usr/bin/sudo /etc/sudoers
```

(you don't seem to have this problem; I include it for completeness)

Since your permissions were broken, it's possible the SELinux labels were also broken.  You should verify the SELinux labels are correct with `ls -Z`:

```
-r--r-----. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       /etc/sudoers
---s--x--x. root root system_u:object_r:sudo_exec_t:s0 /usr/bin/sudo
```

These should be fixable with `restorecon`

```
restorecon -v /usr/bin/sudo /etc/sudoers
```

Finally you may have a totally problem install (eg PAM config, `/etc/sudo.conf`).  You can check to see what files have been modified:

```
rpm --verify sudo
```

If this throws up any files that look off then you might want to delete them and then reinstall sudo.

eg

```
rm /etc/sudo.conf /etc/pam.d/sudo*
yum reinstall sudo
```

(This does require a working `yum` setup so don't do this if your repo's don't work!)

Comment: I have tried these command but they don't work. I have updated my post for the output of ls -Z command.

Comment: OK, doesn't look like you're running SELinux (no labels) so that's possibly not your problem.  I don't see you having run the `chmod 4111 /usr/bin/sudo`.  I've also added additional things to check to the answer.

Comment: rpm --verify sudo return 'S.5....T.  c /etc/sudoers'. Is this correct?

Comment: That seems fine.   As long as `visudo -c` responds OK.

Comment: what else could be the problem?

Comment: I have checked that visudo -c response ok

Answer (score 1):

If `sudo` doesn't work, you can become a root user with `su -`

Later be root, you can re-install **sudo** using these commands below:

> yum remove sudo
>
> yum install sudo

You need to add yourself to /etc/sudoers file, enter:

> visudo

Grant vivek user full permission via sudo:

> vivek   ALL=(ALL) ALL

Save and close the file.
Later do that, you have **sudo**  and you can become a root user using:

> sudo -i

If it doesn't work, use

> sudo -s

Comment: I become root and reinstalled sudo but it still not work. The output of sudo -i and sudo -s are the same as the error I showed on my post.

Comment: OK, anyway, you can be root user with su?

Comment: Yes I can be root with su but other user can't run sudo command.